# Eliminate need for full_title test helper (railstutorial.org [Michale harlt] Chapter 5.6 exercise 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I just completed the Chapter 5 exercises from "[The Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/)" by *Michael Hartl* (which is really great) But exercise 4 from section 5.6, I just don't understand how it works.

I have created integration tests using rspec located in spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:

```
shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
    it { should have_title(full_title(page_title)) }
  end
```

The **full_title** function is located in a support directory under spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
end
```

Which works great. In exercise 4 in 5.6 we are tasked to remove it by adding a helpers directory and application_helper_spec.rb file spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

    describe "full_title" do
        it "should include the page title" do
            expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/foo/)
        end

        it "should include the base title" do
            expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/)
        end

        it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
            expect(full_title("")).not_to match(/\|/)
        end
    end
end
```

and edit utilities.rb to contain just one line spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

and all of my tests pass!

My question is how..? How, after removing the **full_title** util function and only adding the **application_helper_spec** to test **full_title** do my original spec tests pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the question carefully, he's suggesting that there's redundancy in the code that you can refactor further:

> "Eliminate the need for the full_title test helper in Listing 5.29 by
>   writing tests for the original helper method, as shown in Listing
>   5.41."

If we look at listing 5.29, he follows with:

> "Of course, this is essentially a duplicate of the helper in Listing
>   4.2, but having two independent methods allows us to catch any typos in the base title. This is dubious design, though, and a better
>   (slightly more advanced) approach, which tests the original full_title
>   helper directly, appears in the exercises (Section 5.6)."

So, actually, you have already defined this function in your app/helpers/application_helper.rb file. A simple include statement in your spec/support/utilities.rb file will load all of your functions from app/helpers/application_helper.rb and that is why your tests still pass.

Have fun with the rest of the tutorial!

Comment: Thanks yeah I should have checked app/hepers/application_helper.rb based on the fact that I was creating a spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb that makes a lot more sense.  I was just too focused on the utilities.rb and didn't realize what the spec was actually testing.  Thanks!